# COUNT via multi-chain join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have this hierarchy in my database (from lowest to highest):

User => Dept => Area => Company

Now I need to make a table that shows all companies (some info about them taken directly from companies table) but the last column in the HTML table I want to be **Number of users**. I know I need to join the tables together and perhaps join table to itself, but how do I do this?

Each of these tables have a column linking to its parent table (except Company ofc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT
  c.companyId, 
  c.CompanyName,
  IFNULL(COUNT(u.userID), 0) AS 'Number Of Users'
FROM Company    AS c
LEFT JOIN Area  AS a ON c.CompanyID = a.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN Dept  AS d ON a.DeptId    = d.DeptId
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON D.UserId    = u.UserId
GROUP BY c.companyId, 
         c.CompanyName;
```

**Note that:** `LEFT JOIN` with `IFNULL` will give you those companies that has no matched rows in the other tables; with count zero in this case